# Layout display problem on whenever i have to scroll

Tags: android-layout

i want to display two buttons at the bottom of my activity screen, but each time i populate the screen with views that makes me scroll, the two buttons at the bottom of my screen disappears. when there is no need to scroll the buttons display fine.

please help
thanks.

Layout code
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

```
    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/lin_layout_list_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp">

        <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="2px"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            >
            <TableLayout
                android:layout_below="@id/lin_layout_list_view"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_width ="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:stretchColumns="0,1">

                <TableRow
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <Button android:id="@+id/ws_button_back" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" Back "
                        />

                    <Button android:id="@+id/ws_button_ok" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" Ok "/>

                </TableRow>

            </TableLayout>        

        </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Well, there is probably something wrong with your layout. I suppose, but you could've come up with that yourself, you might want to show is the code for your layout, so we can advise you on what might be wrong and wat not?

Comment: please do share your layout, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the buttons along with the scrollable content(e.g:-Listview) in a scrollview and then display the content.

Comment: i have wrapped it in a scrollview but still does not display the buttons at the bottom of my list once i have to scroll. here is the code for my layout.